# Logging-in from iframe in Chrome incognito mode

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, session, iframe, session-cookies

I need to fix a problem which appeared after Chrome v80 which introduced a default option for Cookies of: `Block 3rd Party cookies in Incognito mode`.

Use case:

- site A (https://siteA.com)
- site B (https://siteB.com)
- Site A includes an iframe of Site B, which require logging in

**Problem:**
No session cookie is stored so session could not be started.

*FYI, This work fine in default mode of Chrome.
A cookie setting of: `SameSite=None` is set on Site B.*

Answer (score 0):

It’s been a while since I did something like this but basically the solution is to read the cookie on site A, wait for site B to load in the iframe, and then use the PostMessage API to pass the cookie value to site B and set the Cooke there.

You may run into some issue with JS being blocked from reading a cookie and then passing it, but this can be got around by using async functions.

Alternatively proxy Site B, on Site A.

Comment: This wouldn't work as Site B need to be able to allow navigation to their other subpage. So even if postMessage would return some session_id it won't be transferred to the second page of Site B.

Comment: That is why you set a cookie on site B, when you receive ampostMessage

Comment: But the cookie is not stored in such case, any cookie is wipped out after refresh even when postMessage is sending a session id.

Comment: Store the cookie on SiteA and resend it to SiteB every time you reload

Comment: I should add this deliberately difficult to stop people tracking you